# What additional Rabbinic sources support the Flat Earth?

Tags: sources-mekorot, science, astronomy

[Rasa"G's interpretation of Sefer Hayetzirah 4,2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rasag_on_Sefer_Yetzirah.4.2.1?vhe=Rasage_on_Sefer_Yetzirah,_Warsaw_1884&lang=he) (c.900CE):

> "העולם ככפה, והגלגל אינו זז ממקומו...:
> (the world is like a dome and the sphere [of stars] does not move).

Are there other Rabbinic sources that support the idea of a Flat Earth?

Comment: You push an open door. So what?

Comment: @kouty I'd like that door to be wide open.

Comment: I understand you but there is no nafka minah. Downvote is not mine. Simply I want to say you that everyone needs to build his emunat chachomim as he wants. If someone cannot assume that chachomim were synchronized with their time, so he needs to think they know everything. And subsequently can continue to learn Gemara. After all that is good

Comment: Downvotes not mine but question would be more compelling if you quoted the Rasag into the question, with appropriate translation of the relevant part, so all can see what you are speaking about

Comment: I don't see how this suggests a flat earth. ככיפה sounds like a hemisphere, and what indication is there that the bottom is not the completion of the sphere?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is another Rabbinical source which promotes the idea of a flat earth:

> *The Holy One, blessed be He, raised up all the waters of creation and set half of them in the firmament and half in the Ocean; it is surprising! It is thus written: The river of God is full of water. The firmament is similar to a pool [reservoir] and above the pool is a dome.* (Bereishit Rabbah 4:4-5)

How can a dome cover a spherical earth and be attached to it at the same time? It only works with a flat circular earth IMO.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Where do you see that the dome is attached to the Earth?

Comment: If you put a marble on a plate and cover it with a cheese dome, then the latter rests on the plate (not on the marble), but I don't see how this should work with a spherical earth. It's not a cocoon but a dome, so on what shall a water-dividing dome rest if not on the earth itself?

Answer (score 1):

You ask if there are other Rabbinical sources that support the idea of a Flat Earth? there are some, though they are few.

Whether or not some sages believed in the geocentric view - the sun revolving around the earth or the heliocentric view - the reverse, we still describe our evenings as “sunset”. Our perspectives are based on our assertions which is decided by looking to the horizon.

It has been noted that since antiquity, the Greeks recognized the heliocentric and not the geocentric view, which was the consensus at the time. However, since the antiquity of its history, the Church knew it was round and the size of its circumference. While most Talmudic rabbis endorsed the heliocentric view, there were some who engaged in the geocentric. Of course, the sun’s position is relative to each standing perceptive.

In Ri of Barcelona’s commentary on Sefer Yetzirah (p. 254a), he quotes Rav Saadia Gaon supporting the theory that the earth is flat. This was a minority (miktzat) opinion. Another was Rabbi Yehuda HaNassi who said the underground streams were cold because the sun traveled beneath the earth at night and that this theory seemed more correct. Some Jews believed the sun traveled above, indicating a more flat earth theory. The Lubavitcher, Rabbi Menachem M. Schneerson, of Chabad wrote in a correspondence to a friend of the nonsensical notion that the sun and earth change positions based on the merits or sins of the Jews. Obviously, this nonsensical notion is ridiculed. Magic, demons, and ghost do not exist. They have never been proven and thus belong to the fabrication of the wild imagination of the mystics to support their emotional needs. Maimonides said that some ancient rabbis were little experts in the realms of science and did not always fully understood how the laws of nature worked (Guide to the Perplexed, III:14). For the rationalist, Gersonides (Ragbag), Maimonides (Rambam), and Ibn Ezra were convinced that the sun did not stand still for Joshua nor did the sun’s shadow move ten degrees backward on Hezekiah’s deathbed.

In summary, a few rabbis in the Talmud believed it was flat and some were unsure. In spite of that, the majority knew it had to be round, which was proven by modern science today.

Comment: Most of this doesn't answer the question. Please edit it down.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I believe the comments made therein are relevant to the question.

Comment: This is not a chat forum for posting generally related material. This is a question for sources for flat Earth support. You can post your other material about round Earth sources elsewhere.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the whole point about posting the material about round Earth is for context. Without context the question can not be answered in detail. 2nd, the material works as a bonus to prove Judaism’s validity for readers who do not know. Most people think Judaism is just a backward religion like everyone else but it’s not. So the extra material serves two purposes. What do you suggest I remove?

Comment: Did you use [this site](http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_shape.html) as a source? If so, you should cite whatever your source of information is

Comment: No. I cited all my sources. Not only Gil Student knows the material provided. I.e. he is good rabbi, though.

Comment: All the extra material. If you want to post a different question with sources for round Earth or a different question about is Judaism backwards, you can do so there. This question is just for what it asks for.

Comment: Ok. Good thought.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the answer was both shorted and edited to fit the question respectfully.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good start. I have a strong feeling of us all falling into the confirmation bias - seeking the answers we like and rejecting what we don't like. Each time the sages speak of the earth as round - it is realistic and physical, but every time they see it as flat - it's automatically metaphorical. THe like shows it clearly to me.

Comment: “Magic, demons, and ghost do not exist. They have never been proven and thus belong to the fabrication of the wild imagination of the mystics to support their emotional needs” have you ever heard of seances, or near death experience? No ones ever “proven” that they don’t exist

Comment: @KapinKrunch NDE never took place. There is no proof that they happen.

Comment: 30 million people have experienced NDE, including my mother

Comment: @KapinKrunch My uncle claims to have known a friend who experienced an near-death experience and refuses to talk about it and claims he is depressed because he had to return to the world. The problem lies in that fact that many people claim to have seen Jesus, Mohammad, or even Krinsha. Only Rabbi salon Anava claims for a Kabbalist perspective. What did your mother see?

Comment: What did she see, respectfully?

Answer (score 0):

All biblical and cuneiform texts "posit a flat, probably disk-shaped world. The heavens are made of solid material. They are ... dome-shaped, completely enclosing the surface of the earth." Moshe Simon-Shoshan, "The Heavens Proclaim the Glory of God: A Study in Rabbinic Cosmology," *BDD* 20 (2008): 70.

"[The ancient sages of Israel] believed that the earth is a roughly flat disc, and the rest of the universe is a hemispherical solid dome fixed above it." Natan Slifkin, *The Sun’s Path at Night: The Revolution in Rabbinic Perspectives on the Ptolemaic Revolution* (Jerusalem: Lander Institute, 2010), 4.

Comment: We know they had, I'm specifically looking for clear cut Rabbinical sources. You might want to append this clarification to your existing answer.

Answer (score -2):

I've bumped into probably the last of this camp, [Jacob ben Joseph Reischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Joseph_Reischer) in his Shvut Yaakov SHU"T (c.1730) ([Part 3, Q. 20](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=9540&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=8)) writes angrily against Rambam and other followers of Aristo who try to shake the traditional Jewish Flat Earth approach (couldn't find it in the text form):

[image]

Comment: I don't see him being so against a round earth or being angry at those who hold of it. He says to be careful when accepting things from scientists, and says that he doesn't study hilchos kidush hachodesh for that reason, and that the Gemara sounds like a flat earth. The one of his sources that I could look up, BTW, talks about getting chochma from Torah and not from the goyim, which is more along the thrust of the teshuvah.